# How should I calculate the residuals of my numerical PDE solution?

Tags: hyperbolic-pde, approximation, data-sets, collocation, chebyshev

I solved numerically the following wave equation with a source problem:

$$ u_{rr} + {1 \over r}u_r + u_{zz} = {1 \over c^2}u_{tt} + s(r,z,t) \tag 1 $$

$$ u_r(0,z,t) = 0 \tag 2$$
$$ u_r(r_{max},z,t) = f(z,t) \tag 3$$
$$ u_z(r, 0, t) = g(t) \tag 4$$
$$ u(r, z_{max}, t) = 0 \tag 5$$
$$ u(r,z,0)=0 \tag 6$$
$$ u_t(r,z,0)=0 \tag 6$$

Since I don't have an analytical solution to compare my results to, I would like to calculate the residuals of my simulation. The problem is, I don't have experience with this task. To be more precise, I don't know what is the best method to do it.

I understand the concept of residuals because I went to a statistics course, where I learned about the residuals of a PDE solution being approximated using the collocation method, least squares method, Galerkin method, etc. So the way I understand the process, I need to fit an approximate function through my set of data points. Next, I should just insert that function into my PDE and calculate the residuals.

I used the Chebyshev's collocation method to solve my PDE. If my PDE didn't depend on time, I would probably need to approximate my set of data points using a sum of Chebyshev's polynomials and insert it into my PDE. However, my PDE depends on time, so I don't know what basis functions should I use to approximate my result.

I guess the simplest way to approximate my numerical result is to simply use the collocation method and construct a polynomial that depends on both time and space. Then I just insert that into my PDE and check the residuals. However, I have a feeling that this is not the best way to do it.

So my question is, which approach should I take to find the residuals of my PDE solution? What basis functions should I use for time and space? Should I use the sum of Chebyshev polynomials with time-varying coefficients, and then just approximate the coefficient change with a polynomial?

Comment: What do you want to use this residual for ?

Comment: As a measure of how much my approximate solution satisfies the PDE.

Comment: Without an alternative solution (analytic or from some other reliable code) you can verify grid convergence but you cannot prove that your numerical solution converges to the right result. What you can do is to write a little code for checking the solution, just calculating the derivatives of your $u(r,z,t)$ and finding how well the sum of terms satisfies your Eq. (1); in a sense the sum of terms in Eq.(1) calculated numerically can be called a residual.

Comment: I understand that, but the question is how to analytically approximate $u(r,z,t)$ so I can take its derivatives and calculate the residuals. What would be a good approach?

Comment: The "residual" as used in statistics has nothing to do with the residual of the finite element method, other than the fact that it describes by how much the numerical model is "off". In statistics, the residual is a set of numbers (one for each data point); in the FEM, the residual is an element of the dual space of the solution space.

Comment: I see. I didnt know that. Thank you for the explanation.